# How is this reaction not a decomposition reaction? And are all disproportionation reactions decomposition reactions?

Tags: redox, hydrolysis, decomposition

When I asked my teacher whether all disproportionation reactions are decomposition reactions, he stated the following reaction:

$$ \ce{4 KClO3 -> 3 KClO4 + KCl} $$

and said that this isn't a decomposition reaction and that it is a hydrolysis reaction. How is this not a decomposition reaction as the definition of a decomposition reaction is the splitting of a single reactant into multiple products. I see the same happening here, the singular reactant ($\ce{KClO4}$) is splitting into multiple products ($\ce{KClO4}$, $\ce{KCl}$). And also how is this a hydrolysis reaction as I see no $\ce{H2O}$ molecule taking part in it. It would be great if you answer with some proper explanation to help me understand.

Comment: decomposition implies a more complex thing falls apart into more less complex things. kclo4 is kclo3 plus another atom so it's is the opposite of decomposition. but kcl is less complex so overall it's neither decomposition nor synthesis. that's what we call disproportionation

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, chemical information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, do not use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: Unless IUPAC says something else, that can be a decomposition reaction, at least the decomposition of the solid lattice of the starting salt. But could also be hydrolysis or whatever. I would say one named it in the more useful way giving the context. In fact, you know it is a disproportionation. An internal example of the latter? Perhaps in organic chemistry. I would wait other users for this point, but I am pretty sure the hypothetical reaction(s) would have a better representative name, again.

Comment: $\ce{KClO3 + O -> KClO4}$ does not seem to be to be decomposition.

Comment: (1) If you talk about decomposition, then this is a decomposition reaction: $\ce{2KClO3 -> 2KCl + 3O2}$. (2) The reaction you mentioned is not hydrolysis because there is no water involved.

Comment: First, this is not hydrolysis. Word hydrolysis originate from Ancient Greek hydro- 'water', and lysis 'to unbind'. By definition  it is "any chemical reaction in which a molecule of water breaks one or more chemical bonds". Second, from IUPAC gold book - "decomposition is the breakdown of a single entity (normal molecule, reaction intermediate, etc.) into two or more fragments". Nothing said about complexity of products, so this definition can be used for the given reaction.

Comment: all right @NilayGhosh I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, in the reaction, $\ce{KClO_{3}}$ turns into $\ce{KClO_{4}}$ which is not decomposition as $\ce{KClO_{4}}$ has an extra $\ce{O}$ molecule. Water is not involved so, it is not hydrolysis either. So, we can conclude that all disproportionation reactions are not decomposition reactions.